# Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: powershell

I've read various things on why this error occurs, from the wrong imports when connection to 365 SharePoint, to Load being a Generics method.  The problem is that changing the imports hasn't helped, and I can't see why it, or Generics, would be the answer when else where in my script Load works.

```
$rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
$childWebs = $rootWeb.Webs
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
$clientContext.Load($childWebs)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

function processWeb($web)
{
    $lists = $web.Lists
    $clientContext.Load($web)
    $clientContext.Load($lists)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Web URL is" $web.Url

    foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
        if ($list.BaseTemplate -eq 101)
        {
            Write-Host "`t" $list.Title
        }
    }

    $subs = $web.Webs
    $clientContext.Load($subs)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    processWeb($subs)
}
```

The Loads outside the function work fine.

Remove the last 4 lines inside the function, and the loads inside the function work fine.

With the lines to find the sub sites, and the recursion call, it fails with the error thrown on the first call to Load inside the function.

Take out only the recursion call, and it runs.

So what have I got wrong?

Get-Host return version 5.1........

Regards

Tom

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The full error is:
Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\tom.simmons\Documents\listing 1.ps1:32 char:5
+     $clientContext.Load($lists)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
thrown on line 32, which is the second call to Load in the function - I suspect it really means the line before.